# Basic html5 issue with links/anchor elements?

Tags: html, text, hyperlink

I'm ultimately looking to rebuild an old website that complies to web standards, and thought I would try getting my feet wet in html5 and css3. I know neither of these are fully supported across browsers yet, but I'm willing to work within whatever limits for the time-being.

However, I'm already ramming my head against an early wall, and frankly feel pretty stupid right now. I can't seem to highlight text OR open links in the pages generated by my code.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>The Hominis Inquiry: Reconstructing Psychology, Societies, and Human Ecosystems</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="HIcss3.css" />
        <script src="HIjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <div id="search">
                <form id="searcher" onclick="startSearch('sbox')">
                    <input type="text" id="sbox" size="15" value="Search This Site"> 
                    <input type="button" id="sbutt" value="Find"> 
                </form> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div id="about"> <a href="about.htm"> About </a> </div>
            <div id="blog"> <a href="blog.htm"> Blog </a> </div>
            <div id="research"> <a href="research.htm"> Research/ Academic Papers </a> </div>
            <div id="hypercourse"> <a href="hypercourses"> Hypercourses </a> </div>
            <div id="links"> <a href="links"> Links </a> </div>
            <div id="contact"> <a href="about.htm#contact"> Contact </a> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="download">
            <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/" target="_blank">
                Firefox is strongly recommended for viewing this page. Download the latest version free!<img src="firefox.jpg" />
            </a> 
        </div>

        <p>
            Welcome to HI Updates!
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {border:0; margin:0; padding:0; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; background-color:#FFDDAA; color:#440000}

h1 {font-size:3em; font-weight:700}
h2 {font-size:1.5em; font-weight:600}
h3 {font-size:1.25em; font-weight:500}
p {}

a {color:#000066; font-weight:600; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {background-color:#FFFFDD}
a:visited {color:#440066}

div.title {position:fixed; width:100%; height:10.5em; background-image:url(hominquiry_laeroprocni.jpg); }


div.download {text-align:left} 
div.download img {border:0; float:left; width:3em; height:3em}

div.navigation {}
#about {}
#blog  {}
```

This was not a problem with my last layout in html 4, and feel I must be overlooking something REALLY obvious... even worse, it went through the validator without a hitch :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div.title` is `position: fixed` so it is actually floating over your links, so they don't receive the hover or click events from your mouse. Remove it to try it out.

With: http://jsfiddle.net/LFTpB/

Without: http://jsfiddle.net/THyke/

Comment: Oops, forgot to specify the other element positions before testing. Thanks for pointing that out!